# Trying to clean up my ElasticSearch tracer output

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I use elasticsearch a lot and I needed a way to see the request to elasticsearch server.

So I found this bash script:

```
sudo tcpdump -A -nn -s 0 'tcp dst port 9200 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' -i lo
```

Works well, the problem is it outputs a lot of junk:

```
11:40:49.690863 IP 127.0.0.1.50270 > 127.0.0.1.9200: Flags [P.], seq 2594084191:2594084256, ack 2674569216, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 910075 ecr 910075], length 65
E..uw.@.@............^#...._.j.....V.i.....
..HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Connection: keep-alive


11:40:49.707181 IP 127.0.0.1.50271 > 127.0.0.1.9200: Flags [P.], seq 3009491178:3009491248, ack 3451175088, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 910080 ecr 910079], length 70
E..z..@.@.jc........._#..a0........V.n.....
..GET /_nodes HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Connection: keep-alive


11:40:52.215800 IP 127.0.0.1.50272 > 127.0.0.1.9200: Flags [P.], seq 148869443:148869508, ack 2833610757, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 910707 ecr 910707], length 65
E..ut3@.@..M.........`#....C..x....V.i.....
.sHEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Connection: keep-alive
```

I just want to keep the JSON.

So I though about going by elimination.

I added this regex:

```
 sudo tcpdump -A -nn -s 0 'tcp dst port 9200 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' -i lo | grep -v "[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}\.[0-9]*[ ][I][P][ ][0-9]{1,3}\.[0    -9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]*[ ][\>].*"
```

Here is the regex in action: https://regex101.com/r/aS6kS2/1

Anyways, what I am trying to accomplish here is to remove:

```
11:40:49.707181 IP 127.0.0.1.50271 > 127.0.0.1.9200: Flags [P.], seq 3009491178:3009491248, ack 3451175088, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 910080 ecr 910079], length 70
    E..z..@.@.jc........._#..a0........V.n.....
    ..GET /_nodes HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:9200
    Connection: keep-alive
```

So that only the body/JSON is kept.

I was trying to go line by line but for now it's not even removing the first one that was the target of my regex.

Comment: Hmm, I hope I didn't do this, I have rolled back all my edits, but I still see `[0    -9]` in the middle of your `grep -v` string. Sorry if I goofed it up. ALSO, you might want to show required output (JSON), from your sample inputs. Good luck.

Comment: Don't assume we know what `the body/JSON` is. I don't see any difference between what you get and what you say you want to remove except blank lines. Just post concise, testable sample input and expected output and an explanation of the transformation you want to achieve and a wider audience will be able to help you.

Comment: By removing the lines I shown the only thing that will be left will be the JSON. I am trying to build a black list filter.

Comment: The answer I posted http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660175/1745001 removes the lines you have shown so is the text that is left in my answer "the JSON" and that solves your problem? If not - it doesn't matter what you are trying to build, simply (at a minimum!) show sample input and the expected output given that input in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you've told us about so far (remove the middle chunk of text from the sequence of 3 chunks of text):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR!=2' file
11:40:49.690863 IP 127.0.0.1.50270 > 127.0.0.1.9200: Flags [P.], seq 2594084191:2594084256, ack 2674569216, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 910075 ecr 910075], length 65
E..uw.@.@............^#...._.j.....V.i.....
..HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Connection: keep-alive

11:40:52.215800 IP 127.0.0.1.50272 > 127.0.0.1.9200: Flags [P.], seq 148869443:148869508, ack 2833610757, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 910707 ecr 910707], length 65
E..ut3@.@..M.........`#....C..x....V.i.....
.sHEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9200
Connection: keep-alive
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to clarify as I suggested in my comment.

Comment: The JSON shows under the Connection... Sometimes it doesn't. I am trying to build a black listing filter. So if it fits a pattern just take it out. What will be left will be the JSON. Unless white listing filtering would be faster. Than it's any line with JSON... So anything with { and ending with }. But I am unsure that would be the best way.

Comment: The thing is I might use it for other things too that don't fit the JSON pattern.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. There's only blank lines under Connection in your example - is that what you want output, a bunch of blank lines? You show us a bock of text you want to remove with absolutely no explanation of WHY that should be removed and no apparent correlation to your grep script. It would help a LOT if you'd simply show concise, testable sample input and expected output in your question.